# System.ArgumentException: Parameter '@par_param' does not exist on this report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, parameters, report

First let me say sorry if this has been answered before, but I can't find anything that talks about the problem I am having.

Here is the situation:
I have an ASP web app that uses a SQL DB for data storage and another server for SSRS. I have everything working EXCEPT for pulling the report.

I created the report using BI in visual studio 2015 pro and deployed it to the SSRS server. I am able to connect to the SSRS server and see and execute the report ok.

My problem comes when I try to feed a parameter to the report. I receive the following error:

'System.ArgumentException: Parameter '@par_param' does not exist on this report'

I have traced this to the code behind my VB page for the report viewer load. Here is the code:

```
Dim param As Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter
param = New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("@par_param", par_number)
Me.ParReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(param)
```

I have Imported Microsot.Reporting.WebForms and the variable par_number has been declared as a global variable.

I have searched and searched for an answer to solve this problem but i can not find one. Can anyone tell me how in the world to get this parameter to work??
If I need to post any other code please just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Use "par_param" instead of "@par_param".  I don't think you need the '@'.

Comment: You are the great one!! That did the trick! I don't know why I didn't think of that... Thank you!